# Mac toolbars and menus disappear

Tags: macos, mac

I've recently experienced issues with my Mac. It seems all menus and buttons lose their text and icons. If I rightclick anywhere I just get a blank grey box, the entire top menu bar is empty (including the Apple logo top left) and any new windows I open are just black entirely.

I managed to get a screenshot of the top left menu while trying to reboot it. See image: [image]

Has anyone experienced anything like this before? It's happened a couple of times now. Mac Pro 2017, 15", 10.13.6

Comment: Does this behavior occur if you boot up in Safe Mode?